# Grey screen and crashing after gnome installing on Ubuntu VM 16.04 (GCP)

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, gnome, rdp

I have a VM machine on GCP (Ubuntu 16.04). I'm trying to install a GUI on it using Gnome and xdrp. But each time I have the same grey screen during the RDP connection, and then it crashes at all.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
sudo apt-get install -y xrdp
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Step by Step:

```
cd
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xrdp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xfce4
echo xfce4-session > .xsession
```

Now give it a try from a Windows machine (Windows Remote Desktop) and you will get the xfce4 desktop on the Ubuntu system. It looks different than the console but is fully functional.

---

This information came from

http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=5305

---

Now, to go a little further, in order to be able to reconnect to the same session, do this:

```
cd /etc/xrdp
sudo vi xrdp.ini
```

find the line at the end of the [xrdp1] section that looks like this:

```
port=-1
```

and change it to say

```
port=ask5910
```

save it.

(If you don't do vi then you can use a text editor of your choice)

Now, when you try to login from another machine you will get three prompts. Username, password, and port. Port will be prefilled with 5910. If this is your first session you change the 5910 to -1 after entering username and password.

Then if you disconnect and want to reconnect, just leave it as 5910 and it will reconnect to the same session.

Original Post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464389/xrdp-gray-screen-tried-everything) , you can try the other answer posted there.

Comment: Thanks! I have already installed xfce4. It works fine, but scrolling isn't smooth